Automatically Updating Images in Slides Using python-pptx
I'm currently working with the python-pptx library to manage PowerPoint presentations. I have images in the slides linked to online sources and I want these images to update automatically whenever the presentation is opened, referencing their original online sources.
I've been working with a Python script using the python-pptx library where I try to auto-update the images in my pptx file from their respective online sources. However, I've encountered an issue where it seems like my PowerPoint blocks the download of the images. Below is the code I have been using:
def fetch_image(url, path):
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in response:
                f.write(chunk)
    else:
        logging.error(f"Failed to fetch image from {url}")

def update_relationships_rels(temp_dir, slide_index, image_name, rId):
    rels_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, f'ppt/slides/_rels/slide{slide_index}.xml.rels')
    logging.info(f"Updating relationships file at {rels_path}")
    with open(rels_path, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()

    new_rel = f'<Relationship Id="{rId}" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="../media/{image_name}"/>'
    if f'Id="{rId}"' in content:
        content = re.sub(f'<Relationship Id="{rId}".*?/>', new_rel, content)
    else:
        content = content.replace('</Relationships>', f'    {new_rel}\n</Relationships>')

    with open(rels_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)

def update_slide_xml(temp_dir, slide_index, rId):
    slide_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, f'ppt/slides/slide{slide_index}.xml')
    logging.info(f"Updating slide file at {slide_path}")

    tree = ET.parse(slide_path)
    root = tree.getroot()

    namespaces = {
        'a': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main',
        'r': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships'
    }

    for blip in root.findall('.//a:blip', namespaces):
        if blip.get('{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships}embed') == rId:
            blip.set('{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships}link', rId)
            blip.set('autoUpdate', 'true')

    tree.write(slide_path, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')

def update_pptx_images(pptx_path, image_mappings):
    temp_dir = 'temp_pptx'
    with zipfile.ZipFile(pptx_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(temp_dir)

    for mapping in image_mappings:
        slide_index = mapping['slide_index'] + 1
        shape_index = mapping['shape_index']
        shape_name = mapping['shape_name']
        visual_url = mapping['visual_url']

        image_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, f'ppt/media/{shape_name}.jpeg')
        fetch_image(visual_url, image_path)
        rId = f'rId{shape_index + 1}'
        update_relationships_rels(temp_dir, slide_index, f'{shape_name}.jpeg', rId)
        update_slide_xml(temp_dir, slide_index, rId)

    media_dir = os.path.join(temp_dir, 'ppt/media')
    for file_name in os.listdir(media_dir):
        if file_name not in [f'{mapping["shape_name"]}.jpeg' for mapping in image_mappings]:
            os.remove(os.path.join(media_dir, file_name))

    new_pptx_path = 'updated_' + os.path.basename(pptx_path)
    shutil.make_archive(new_pptx_path.replace('.pptx', ''), 'zip', temp_dir)
    shutil.move(new_pptx_path.replace('.pptx', '.zip'), new_pptx_path)
    shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
    return new_pptx_path

The PowerPoint presentation now has a shape with the hyperlink, but it blocks the image from loading. I've already tried to manually change the trust settings inside the PowerPoint, but the issue still persists.
Could someone please help me understand why my images are getting blocked and how I can prevent it from happening? Thank you.
